# Rename file if it is the only one with the extension in directory

Tags: shell, find, rename

This works however I would like to do it only if it is the only `.jpg` for the given directory, the one below will just rename them all to `folder.jpg`, overwriting the other files:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -execdir mv {} 'folder.jpg' \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `find` cannot filter by the number of matches, but you can always exec a shell which does more elaborate checks for you:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c '[ $# = 1 ] && mv "$1" folder.jpg' sh {} +
```

Comment: If the arguments exceeds `ARG_MAX` the script will run more than once and the file overwritten though

Comment: I thought about `ARG_MAX` too but did not want to worry OP with a problem that probably won't occur. Funnily enough, often this command even works when `ARG_MAX` is exceeded, unless you get very unlucky. `-execdir sh -c '[ $# = 1 ] && [ $(find -type f -name \*.jpg -printf . | wc -c) = 1 ] && mv "$1" folder.jpg' sh {} +` could be a possible but slow solution for these cases.

Comment: Another alternative would be to keep track of visited directories

Comment: modified to not move folder.jpg to folder.jpg `find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" ! -name "folder.jpg" \) -execdir sh -c '[ $# = 1 ] && mv "$1" folder.jpg' sh {} +`